# Kotlin array check values

Tags: android, arrays, listview, kotlin

```
 val finallist: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
 for(element in 1 until list.size){
     if(list[element] != list[element - 1]){
         finallist.add(list[element])
     }
 }
```

How can I check if a value is equal to any value inside array? This way I can only check from the previous element

Comment: `valueToCheck in list` or `list.contains(valueToCheck)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to check value exist in Array list or not

Check blow code to check arraylist contain value or not using Kotlin

```
val arrayList= listOf<String>("A","B","C","D","E")
    val value="B"
    //using contain method
    if(arrayList.contains(value)){
        Log.i("Check_Value","true: Contain method")
    }

    //using for loop
    for(item in arrayList){
        if(item.equals(value)){
            Log.i("Check_Value","True for loop")
        }
    }
```

**Check and remove duplicate values from array list**

```
 val arrayList= listOf<String>("A","B","C","D","E","A","A","E")
    val newArrayList=ArrayList<String>()
    //using for loop
    for(item in arrayList){
        if(!newArrayList.contains(item)){
            newArrayList.add(item)
        }else{
            Log.i("Check_Duplicate_values","-- ${item}")
        }
    }
    Log.i("final_List","-- ${newArrayList}")
```

> Result : 
>   I/Check_Duplicate_values: -- A

I/Check_Duplicate_values: -- A

I/Check_Duplicate_values: -- E

**I/final_List: -- [A, B, C, D, E]**

Comment: that checks if the value is equal to "B" what i need to know is if any value inside the array is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
    val finallist: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
        var i=0
        var j=0
        while(i <list.size){
            while(j<list.size){
                if(list[i] != list[j])
                    j++
if(i==j)
                j++
            else break}
            if(j!=list.size)
       finallist.add(list[i]) 
        i++}
```

Comment: that makes the app stop, no response whatsoever

Comment: It depends to list.size, check your list

Comment: like what? the size depends on how many values i get from database

Comment: It had a small bug, I modified it